# Perl multithreading - quit on first thread success

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm by no means an expert in perl or multithreading but I'm convinced I'm "doing it wrong" and need some guidance as to how to alter it so that I don't get thread quit warnings.

As you can see, this program reads in argument 0, does a lookup to find each of the IP addresses associated with a host name, then tests each IP to see if ssh is running.

The purpose of this script is to spawn a tcp test for each host and return the first successful tcp connect.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this that is more reliable and doesn't require a sleep?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    use Config;
    $Config{useithreads} or die('Recompile Perl with threads to run this program.');
}
use threads;
use IO::Socket::INET;
$| = 1;

unless($ARGV[0]){ die("error please use argument")}

my $timeoutval=3;
my $testHost=$ARGV[0];
my $dlquery=`dig $testHost | grep 'IN A'`;
my $SUCCESS=0;

sub testSSHhost {
    my $fqdn = shift;
    my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
            PeerHost => $fqdn,
            PeerPort => '22',
            Proto => 'tcp',
            Timeout => $timeoutval,
    ) or return "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

    my $tcpData = <$socket>;
    $socket->close();
    if ($tcpData && $tcpData=~/SSH/){
            print "$fqdn\n";
            $SUCCESS=1;
            exit(0);
    }
    return $fqdn;
}

my @threads;
for my $line (split(/\n/,$dlquery)){
    my @linesplit=split(/ /,$line);
     $linesplit[0]=~s/\.$//;
     $linesplit[0]=~s/ *//g;
     my $t = threads->new(\&testSSHhost, $linesplit[0]);
     push(@threads,$t);
}

while (!$SUCCESS){sleep 0.3}
```

Really what i'm trying to avoid is the "A thread exited while 2 threads were running." error message
Or a "segmentation fault" message

Comment: Please use `strict` and `warnings`.  Check for `useithreads` in a BEGIN block so that you check *before* you `use threads`.  (I know, I know, `perlthrtut` is misleading here.)  IO::Socket::INET reliably returns errors in `$@`, not `$!` — sad/strange but true!  `$fqdn` doesn't need to be quoted as your PeerHost parameter.  `$SUCCESS` isn't `share()`d, so your main thread will never see the update.  Everyone's a critic, but [perlcritic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/) is often worth listening to.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (**not tested!**):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use IO::Socket::INET;
$| = 1;

my $testHost = $ARGV[0];
my $dlquery  = `dig $testHost | grep 'IN A'`;
my $config   = { NUMBER_OF_THREADS => 5 };      #how many threads you gonna use?

my $queue           = Thread::Queue->new;
my $queue_processed = Thread::Queue->new;

for my $line ( split( /\n/, $dlquery ) ) {
    my ($ip) = split( / /, $line );
    $ip =~ s/\.$//;
    $ip =~ s/ *//g;

    $queue->enqueue($ip);
}

foreach my $thread_id ( 1 .. $config->{NUMBER_OF_THREADS} ) {

    $queue->enqueue(undef);
    my $thread = threads->create( \&testSSHhost() )->detach();
}

while ( $queue->pending() ) {

    my $result = $queue_processed->dequeue();

    if ( $result->{status} ) {

        say $result->{ip};
    }
}

sub testSSHhost {

    while ( my $fqdn = $queue->dequeue() ) {

        my $status = 0;

        my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
            PeerHost => $fqdn,
            PeerPort => 22,
            Proto    => 'tcp',
            Timeout  => 3,
        ) or return "ERROR in Socket Creation : $!\n";

        my $tcpData = <$socket>;
        $socket->close();
        if ( $tcpData && $tcpData =~ /SSH/ ) {

            $status = 1;
        }

        $queue_processed->enqueue( { ip => $fqdn, status => $status, } );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with Qeues:
http://search.cpan.org/dist/Thread-Queue/lib/Thread/Queue.pm

Before spawning the threads, you create a queue, and then let the threads push the successful IP address in it. Then the parent process would block in dequeuing until something pops up.

Comment: Can anyone provide a simple example of how to do this with queues.  I've read through the documentation but nothing has come back.  Are you meant to lock the queue from within a successful thread then dequeue every other thread?

Comment: gangabass provided more details few minutes ago

Comment: Good suggestion but not on point — if the OP merely `exit()`s after the first dequeue, he'll suffer the same error.